# Converting CoffeeScript Higher Order Function into Haskell

Tags: haskell, coffeescript

Reading the excellent [CoffeeScript Ristretto](https://leanpub.com/coffeescript-ristretto/read#fargs), I ran into this function:

```
((x) ->
  (y) ->
    x
)(1)(2)
```

My understanding is that the result `x` is the same as the input `x`.

Would the Haskell version(*) look like this?

```
foo :: a -> b -> (a -> b) -> a
foo x y f = x
```

*Note - I don't know if there's a 1-1 translation given Haskell's robust type system v. CoffeeScript

Comment: Why your `foo` has three parameters?

Comment: Ah, I think that I was forgetting that all of Haskell's functions are curried. So `foo :: a -> b -> a` (as [@Benesh](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2212478/benesh) pointed out) is the same as the above CoffeeScript function. But, as I just read, a closure is used here. So, I'm not sure if the Haskell version is equivalent...

Comment: Does `foo = \x -> \y -> x` or `(\x -> \y -> x) 1 2` look more like your original function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for `const`:

```
const :: a -> b -> a
```

A "functional" look at `const` is that for all `x :: a`, `const x` is the constant function of type `b -> a` - it returns `x` for any value.

A possible implementation is:

```
const x y = x
```

So `const 1 2 == 1`.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a direct translation to Haskell is

```
(\x -> \y -> x) 1 2
```

So you can define that `foo` as

```
foo = \x -> \y -> x
```

This is `const`, as pointed out by @Benesh.